# Error: Could not find or load main class 6.0\glassfish.lib.grizzly-npn-api.jar

Tags: java, web, netbeans, glassfish

Estoy trabajando con [apache-netbeans](/questions/tagged/apache-netbeans) 17 y estoy tratando de instalar glassfish 6.2.5 pero me sale el siguiente error

> Error: Could not find or load main class 6.0\glassfish.lib.grizzly-npn-api.jar

alguien sabe que hacer, por favor

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola eriel, bienvenido, podrías mostrarnos como estás instalando, indicarnos en que plataforma trabajas, y todo dato que ayude a orientarnos acerca de tu problema?, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.